# Execute Kotlin scripts inside java Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, build.gradle, scriptengine

I am trying to execute above kotlin script inside my java spring boot application.

```
public class ScriptExectuorServImpl {

    public void execute() throws ScriptException {

    ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByExtension("kts");
    engine.eval(("println('OK')"));

    }

}
```

My gradle dependencies are

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.6.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    runtime 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-util'
    runtime 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable'
    runtime 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable'
}
```

I'm facing the below error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/kotlin/scripting/compiler/plugin/repl/GenericReplCompiler
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.script.jsr223.KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine$replCompiler$2.invoke(KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine.kt:47) ~[kotlin-script-util-1.3.71.jar:1.3.71-release-431 (1.3.71)]
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.script.jsr223.KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine$replCompiler$2.invoke(KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine.kt:38) ~[kotlin-script-util-1.3.71.jar:1.3.71-release-431 (1.3.71)]
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74) ~[kotlin-stdlib-1.3.71.jar:1.3.71-release-431 (1.3.71)]
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.script.jsr223.KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine.getReplCompiler(KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine.kt) ~[kotlin-script-util-1.3.71.jar:1.3.71-release-431 (1.3.71)]
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.script.jsr223.KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine$localEvaluator$2.invoke(KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine.kt:53) ~[kotlin-script-util-1.3.71.jar:1.3.71-release-431 (1.3.71)]
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.script.jsr223.KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine$localEvaluator$2.invoke(KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine.kt:38) ~[kotlin-script-util-1.3.71.jar:1.3.71-release-431 (1.3.71)]
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74) ~[kotlin-stdlib-1.3.71.jar:1.3.71-release-431 (1.3.71)]
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.script.jsr223.KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine.getLocalEvaluator(KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine.kt) ~[kotlin-script-util-1.3.71.jar:1.3.71-release-431 (1.3.71)]
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.script.jsr223.KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine.getReplEvaluator(KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine.kt:55) ~[kotlin-script-util-1.3.71.jar:1.3.71-release-431 (1.3.71)]
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.script.jsr223.KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine.createState(KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine.kt:59) ~[kotlin-script-util-1.3.71.jar:1.3.71-release-431 (1.3.71)]
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.repl.KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.createState$default(KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.kt:46) ~[kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.71.jar:1.3.71-release-431 (1.3.71)]
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.repl.KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.getCurrentState(KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.kt:53) ~[kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.71.jar:1.3.71-release-431 (1.3.71)]
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.repl.KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.nextCodeLine(KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.kt:44) ~[kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.71.jar:1.3.71-release-431 (1.3.71)]
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.repl.KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.compileAndEval(KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.kt:61) ~[kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.71.jar:1.3.71-release-431 (1.3.71)]
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.repl.KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.eval(KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.kt:31) ~[kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.71.jar:1.3.71-release-431 (1.3.71)]
    at java.scripting/javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264) ~[java.scripting:na]
    at com.example.scriptexecutor.service.ScriptExectuorServImpl.execute(ScriptExectuorServImpl.java:15) ~[main/:na]
```

I have added org.jetbrains.kotlin.script.jsr223.KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngineFactory under resourcs/META-INF/services/javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory

Comment: I want to run kotlin scripts using javax.script api in a spring boot gradle application.

Comment: The `org/jetbrains/kotlin/scripting/compiler/plugin/repl/GenericReplCompiler` class is supposed to be in the `kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable-1.3.72.jar` file (or whichever version you use), so check you dependencies again.

Comment: I'm using kotlin version 1.3.71 buit in with intellij IDE. gradle shows unable to resolve  compile 'org.jetbrains:kotlin:kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable'

Comment: Between `jetbrains` and `kotlin` should be a `.` period, which is weird, because your supposed Gradle script has period, and you copy/pasted both here, to make sure we see exactly what you have, right?

Comment: there was a typo. I tried chaning to compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable'.  Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable:.
     Required by:
         project :

Comment: What version are you trying to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this error by adding kotlin version against the libraries.

rootProject.kotlinVersion=1.3.72

My final list of dependencies required to kick start my spring boot application are

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${rootProject.kotlinVersion}"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-runtime:${rootProject.kotlinVersion}"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-util:${rootProject.kotlinVersion}"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:${rootProject.kotlinVersion}"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable:${rootProject.kotlinVersion}"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-jvm-host-embeddable:${rootProject.kotlinVersion}"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-jvm-host:${rootProject.kotlinVersion}"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-jvm:${rootProject.kotlinVersion}"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-jsr223-embeddable:${rootProject.kotlinVersion}"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-jsr223:${rootProject.kotlinVersion}"
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
```